# Get Child view in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout

I want to add one button in my activity that will return all child view of relative layout.

How can i get all child view of relative layout view?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` extends `ViewGroup` which has the `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt(int index)` methods. So what you could try is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < relativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
   View child = relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
   // your processing...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just the child count for the view and iterate over each of them.
Something like this :

```
int childCount = myRelativeLayout.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    View v = myRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
    // do whatever you want to with the view
}
```

Hope this helps.